# PySide6 updating GUI text from a loop in a thread

Tags: pyside, pyside6

What I am trying to do is creating a separate thread from the GUI, and then in a loop, update the GUI text in every 0.01 second. I came up with the following code by searching the web, but it seems that the app gets stuck at the while loop. Isn't the `count()` supposed to run in another thread? What is wrong?

```
import sys
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QThreadPool, Slot
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    Count = 1;

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.MyButton = QPushButton()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MyButton)
        self.threadManager = QThreadPool();

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.threadManager.start(self.count())

    def count(self):
        while(True):
            self.Count+=1;
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, "refreshButtonText");
            time.sleep(0.01)

    @Slot()
    def refreshButtonText(self):
        self.MyButton.setText(f"Count {self.Count}")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

PS: Updated the code above to be a working example, in case future people find this post when they search for a minimal example of updating the GUI in a long-running task in QT/PySide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally called `count` instead of passing it as a function.

```py
self.threadManager.start(self.count)
```

Instead of directly accessing objects in another thread consider using signal-slot mechanism to send data messages.

You can easily find out which thread something runs in by

```py
print("I'm running in", QThread.currentThread())
```

Instead of thread you can just use timer

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    Count = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.MyButton = QPushButton()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.MyButton)
        
    def showEvent(self, event):
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.count)
        timer.start(10)

    def count(self):
        self.Count+=1
        self.refreshButtonText()

    def refreshButtonText(self):
        self.MyButton.setText(f"Count {self.Count}")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: I am new to both Python AND QT, and I was trying to find an example of running a long job and reporting the status, so timer is not suitable in this case. I tested my original method (with `count()` fixed) and your new timer method, and it seems that with my original way, `count` is running in a different thread and with the timer way, `count` is running in the GUI thread. So, QT doesn't throw an exception, unlike WinForms or Android. But if I want to be safe, can I call `refreshButtonText` in the GUI thread when `count` is running in another thread? In C#, there's `Invoke`.

Comment: C++ is unmanaged, so instead of exception you may expect undefined behaviour (likely segfault). But python has GIL, which I believe acts like mutex in this case, so access to shared memory is syncronized. Qt's analog to c sharp invoke is `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.

Comment: Consider using signal-slot mechanism to send progress messages from worker thread to gui thread, take a look at pyside example [thread_signals.py](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/widgets/thread_signals/thread_signals.py?h=v6.6.0)